# I have this error in symfony 2.4.5 BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have this error comes up on Symfony 2.4.5 for symblog tutorial [[Part 4] - The Comments Model: Adding comments, Doctrine Repositories and Migrations], Unexpected token "name" of value "with" ("end of statement block" expected) in BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig. This happend just after updating the blog show template to render the add blog form.

Comment: I found the answer for this use {{ render(controller( 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new', { 'blog_id': blog.id } )) }} instead of using {% render 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new' with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a change after symfony 2.3.

In `show.html.twig`, change this line:

```
{% render 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new' with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}
```

to:

```
{{ render(controller( 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new', { 'blog_id': blog.id } )) }}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!  I am so glad that stuff like this gets posted on stackoverflow!  It makes quality examples that are a little out of date, still relevant and useful.